# Linux keyboard shortcut

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, shortcut

Why on my Linux VS Code installation *"Close window"* shortcut is different: I want to use `ctrl+w` as I do on mac and as I do on any browser, but now I must do `ctrl-f4`

Comment: look at the `File` menu and see which keybinding there is for each `Close` command

Answer (score 0):

**Customize a keyboard shortcut**

On the menu bar, choose Tools > Options.

Expand Environment, and then choose Keyboard.

In the list, choose the command to which you want to assign a keyboard shortcut.

In the Use new shortcut in list, choose the feature area in which you want to use the shortcut.